# Can no longer click in VirtualBox Guest window area after Partial Upgrade

Tags: virtualbox, mouse

I have been flummoxed searching for this topic so please excuse the ignorance.

I run a WordPress development environment (and general Linux learning system) in VirtualBox under Windows. Earlier today I got an Ubuntu upgrade dialog where it offered a "Partial Upgrade". I'm afraid I've never seen that dialog before but as it seemed like a previous one where I did a "non partial" upgrade (it listed changes to packages, talked about packages being removed, etc.) so I clicked it. After going through 4 steps (the final being the removal of packages such as old kernel stuff) I was prompted to reboot so I did.

When the desktop came up again I was alerted to a new version of Guest Additions so I went to install them. However when I went to click the Run button nothing happened. I tried right-clicking on the run script and no menu appeared. I tried to close the window and nothing happened. I went to restart but none of the upper right icons showed tooltips or responded to the mouse. I turned off the virtual machine.

After the next startup I was in the same position. I could click on any of the shortvuts on the left bar including the app drawer. I could start any application but that's where things ended. I started a terminal and could type in it so I looked up how to install Guest Additions via the shell and that worked so I did a "sudo reboot' hoping that the problem was with Guest Additions. But no, still stuck.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS according to the About page of Settings (which I launched by clicking the app drawer and typing "about").

Bottom Line:

- System is running and accessible from Host (both web and sql servers)
- Can start applications from launcher and app drawer
- Can use terminal
- Cannot click on anything within the "window area"
- Cannot click on or get usual tips from Network, Sound or Power icons in upper right

I'm truly lost so any help is greatly appreciated!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

The offer of a "partial upgrade" is usually bad news.

**Lesson**: The offer of a Partial Upgrade is a red flag that your system is at risk of keeling over and dying. Apt couldn't calculate a complete release-upgrade. It is a symptom of (perhaps unintended) human mismanagement of the package system: Unwise sources, incompatible-version packages, abuse of the `--force` flag, too many apt-pins and holds...and then telling apt to try to release-upgrade from that fragile state.

**Action**: Preserve any data that you wish to save, wipe the old VM, and start anew with a fresh 22.04 install.

- Fixing may be possible, or may not -- diagnosis requires simply reading and learning to understand apt's output. However, there is a bit of a learning curve.
- Reinstalling is much faster. It's your choice, of course, which alternative you want to pursue.

**Prevention**:

1. Before agreeing to a release-upgrade, disable PPAs and other non-Ubuntu sources. Uninstall wrong-version software from those sources. Release apt-hold and apt-pins. Backup your data. Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible.
2. After a successful release-upgrade, review the new versions of software in the Ubuntu Repositories. When possible, try to use those versions instead of PPAs or Upstreams or other non-Ubuntu sources. Keep track of what you install, why you installed it, and what source you installed it from.

Comment: Other than XAMPP I didn't install anything. I appreciate the advice. I'd certainly prefer it if I had some way to fix this bizarre behavior, as in how is it even possible for the mouse to click on some areas and not others, but if I have to start over I guess I will soon enough.

Comment: "*I just did XYZ*" is all it takes, if XYZ was done in certain ways, and not completely removed before the release-upgrade. At least now you know what to avoid next time.

Comment: I have now done a fresh install and the same problem has occurred even before I got my shared folder set up for hosting so at least the broken install can be use for development.